# Mysql interprets 00:00:00 as 12:00am?

Tags: php, mysql

So mysql has a  time(type) in which it has a 24 hour clock stored that can ouput time in am/pm format  with the mysql function date_format(). The only problem is that when the user doesnt select the time, the value that stores in the mysql database is 00:00:00 which turns out to be 12:00am when i echo it with php. So how would i frame it so it can tell a difference between a null value and 00:00:00 which is 12:00am? (Btw, i try inserting null into the time column, turns out to be 00:00:00, which is 12:00am).

Comment: 00:00:00 has always been 12AM.. ;)

Comment: What is the definition of the table (or column more exactly)? Is it assigning a default value?

Comment: Are you sure you cannot set the column to NULL ? If not, you may need to add another column with a flag. But NULL should work....

Comment: i justed figured i needed to check the null box in php my admin to have a null value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how would i frame it so it can tell
>   a difference between a null value and
>   00:00:00 which is 12:00am? (Btw, i try
>   inserting null into the time column,
>   turns out to be 00:00:00, which is
>   12:00am).

Make the column nullable. (Remove the NOT NULL constraint.)

Comment: ok i was using phpmyadmin and there was a checkbox for null, i checked it (which i think made the column nullable) and every time there wasnt a value inserted it was -00:00:00 , which i think would be fine. Thanks

Comment: @Ben: MySQL is full of such gotchas. You should think about switching a proper RDBMS or at least play around with SQL compatibility modes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

Its far better to validate the user input field by keeping select time field as a  mandatory one.

Thanks